# Sql Syntax Performance

Tags: sql, optimization, sql-update

Which is better

```
Update TableA
SET TableA.ColumnB = TableB.ColumnB
FROM Table B
WHERE TableB.ColumnA = 1
    AND TableA.ColumnC = TableB.ColumnC
```

OR

```
Update TableA
SET TableA.ColumnB = TableB.ColumnB
From TableA
INNER JOIN Table B ON TableA.ColumnC = TableB.ColumnC
WHERE TableB.ColumnA = 1
```

I think that the first approach is easier to read, but I don't know which version is actually better, if either version actually have any difference in speed when run on large tables.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Benchmark it, compare the results ....

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is too narrow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My preference is to use ANSI-style joins (INNER JOIN, etc) rather than "old-style" joins. I find it easier to determine what the join criteria are because the ON clause immediately follows the name of the joined table, and likewise it's easier to see what's being used as a filter because the WHERE clause is not cluttered up with all the join criteria.

In my experience there's no performance difference (Oracle).

Share and enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

Depends.

All other things being equal, SQL evaluates joins in the from clause before it evaluates joins in the where clauses.  The thing is we don't know if TableB.ColumnA is indexed and what the cardinality of it is.  We don't know if TableA.ColumnC or TableB.ColumnC are indexed.  We don't know the number of records in each, nor do we know whether or not there are statistics that would help the optimizer.

Ask yourself how many rows will need to be scanned to evaluate TableB.ColumnA = 1.  Then ask yourself how many rows will need to be scanned to evaluate TableA.ColumnC = TableB.ColumnC.  You will want the join that returns the fewest rows based on the fewest rows scanned to be first.

If TableB.ColumnA is indexed as is TableA.ColumnC = TableB.ColumnC then both queries should work equally well, since the optimizer will answer the questions for you.

All that being said, the easies solution is to look at the execution plan for both.